# Firestore cannot be created due to Org Policy enforcement

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I created a new project in Firebase. When I try to create a Firestore, get this error: Firestore cannot be created due to Org Policy enforcement. What policy can potentially block the Firestore from creating? [image]

Comment: I am only going with what i see from your screen. I see "location". Check [logs](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/defining-locations#location_types) for location constraint...

Answer (score 0):

This is a restriction on either your region or your account, I suggest contacting Firebase support who can evaluate your GCP account and find if there are any issues with it directly or if there are problems with your geolocation.

https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact